# Moving SignalR object between HTML pages

Tags: javascript, json, html, signalr

I use `SignalR` on `JavaScript`.

I have two objects: an `Connection` object and an  `Hub Proxy` object:

```
 var connection = $.hubConnection();
 connection.url = 'http://localhost:xxx/signalr';
 var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('ChatHub');
```

I want these two objects to be recognized in some `HTML` pages, I tried to put them in `SessionStorage` so I had to convert them to JSON:

```
 sessionStorage["connection"]= JSON.stringify(connection);
 sessionStorage["proxyHub"]= JSON.stringify(contosoChatHubProxy);
```

I got the following error:

```
"Converting circular structure to JSON"
```

I found about this information in several places, and everywhere was written that should determine the **real object**.

The question is what is the real object?

Below there is a picture of the connection object from Console:

[image]

Or is there another way to pass object between pages without converting it? **(without cookies)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new page requires a new connection. Would love to be proven wrong.

Comment: I would be happy if it was not true. But unfortunately I came to the same conclusion! Thanks anyway.